# 301 redirect old urls in subdirectory to new urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I have changed the url structure on a wordpress site and need to 301 the old urls to the new ones. The old structure was as follows:

```
/news/[category-name]/[post-url-slug]
```

So it was always /news then it would have the url slug for the category and then the url slug for the post name.

The new structure is as follows:

```
/[post-url-slug]
```

So I have basically got rid of the news and category name portion of the url. How would I 301 all the old urls to the new ones in my htaccess? mod rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Provide some examples of old and new URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess or apache config:

```
RewriteRule ^news/.+?/(.+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

You might want to be more specific than `.+` depending on the rules for your category and post names.  Eg: `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+` or similar.

Have a play on debuggex if needed:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Nky_ITFDueDoHYbT)